# Browser not sending correct jsessionId for weblogic server?

Tags: java, cookies, browser, weblogic, jsessionid

My app url is `http://localhost:7001/customer`

When i hit this url browser(firefox/chrome) sends some jsessionId(say 100) to back end (app server). Weblogic creates new jsessionId(say 200) as 100 does not exist and
send it back as response header. Now whenever hit my app url it should send 200 but its still sending stale jsessionId i.e 100

If i use same code with tomcat, it works as expected. I am not sure why correct jsessionId is not sent in case of weblogic ?
Muy guess is  weblogic is by default sending some cookie or response header which is restricting browser sending the latest jssession.
I am not sure what it is or what can be other reason?

I shifted to weblogic 12.2.1 from tomcat 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emilly, use your browsers web developer extension (chrome >> f12 >> network tab) to figure out which cookies is the browser sending to the server. Sometimes there can be multiple cookies with the same name sent to the server and it is perhaps picking up one at random. Cleaning up the cookies and retrying may help.

Alternatively you can use a tool like fiddler to see the cookies sent over the request

Comment: you are correct . Thanks. But still ideally browser should use latest cookies sent by server why its using stale cookies.

Comment: Browser will send all cookies for a domain till they expire. If you use a fully qualified domain name; and cookies have the right expiry / session attributes set; such problems shouldnt occur. I have randomly seen some of these issues during development phases when we tend to use localhost more often